# Is asking why code I know is bad on-topic for Code Review?

Tags: support, scope

I have some code I know is bad practice. And I only want to know why it is bad practice. So I can justify changing it to my non-tech boss.

Is Code Review a good place to ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

We only review code from an [author or maintainer of the code](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294) to avoid legal, moral and practical problem. For your case, since the code is not yours (the company you work for owns it) your question would be off-topic to avoid legal problems.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I had read about that rule. However, what if I ask the same question with code that I own myself? Would it be ok then?

Comment: @Shiverz Yes if you implement something similar in your own time and want a review of code that is yours then that's fine.